# repeat linq to sql inside foreach?

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-sql, search-engine

I am working on a (quick and dirty) search engine, using linq to sql. I already have a table of strings containing each word I want to search inside the descriptions of each entry.

In the end of my linq to sql process, I should get only the entries containing **all** the words from my table. Here is the code I have so far (**m1** is my table of strings) :

```
var myUser = from u in dataBase.Profiles
             where u.Status == 2 // some primary selection
             select u;
foreach (string word in m1)
{
  myUser = from u in myUser
           where ((word != "") ? u.Description.Contains(word) : 1 == 1)
           select u;
}
myUser = from u in myUser
         orderby u.ModificationDate descending // finally, we order the list
         select u;
```

This code works nicely, but sadly, it does not select entries containing **both** words, but all the entries containing **at least one word**.

Can you understand why? I don't : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

> Closures close over variables, not over values.

Try assigning the string to a local variable:

```
foreach (string word2 in m1)
{
    string word = word2;
    myUser = from u in myUser
           where ((word != "") ? u.Description.Contains(word) : 1 == 1)
           select u;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the first solution did it. Sadly, the second one looked fancier but did not work when I tried to "foreach" myUser later in the code.

Comment: @BraveKenny: OK, sorry. I guess that I made an error. I didn't test the code, it was just from memory. I removed the second version. The first version is not clean, but it works.